# Place du pronom en présence d'un verbe conjugué et l'infinitif

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots, constructions-causatives, verbes-de-perception

Cette exception est issue des pages 162-163 de *Advanced French Grammar* de V. Mazet.

> With certain verbs, the placement doesn't follow the normal rules mentioned earlier. With faire faire, laisser faire, envoyer chercher, falloir, and the verbs of perception, the pronoun precedes the conjugated verb, NOT the infinitive.

Pourquoi ? Voici un exemple de Léon Thiessé : ([Source](http://books.google.com/books?id=PB5HAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22l%27a+envoye+chercher%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=ToyuUsOaO8PQiAe9vYHwAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22l%27a%20envoye%20chercher%22&f=false))

> Sa présence produit une vive agitation; on répand qu'une seule voix peut empêcher la condamnation à mort. Charlier demande que le malade soit interpellé sur la question de savoir qui est allé l'instruire, qui **l'a envoyé chercher**. Seconds fait observer qu'en traversant la salle, il a entendu dire par Duchastel : *Je ne suis venu que pour cela.*

Pourquoi pas : « qui a envoyé *le* chercher » où *le* = *le malade* ?

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a pas de raison particulière.  À noter que contrairement à ce que l'extrait laisse croire, ce déplacement n'est pas systématique ni obligatoire.

Si je le ferai toujours avec *faire faire* et très souvent pour *laisser faire*, il me semble qu'avec *envoyer chercher* et *falloir*, le déplacement est plutôt d'un registre recherché.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas certain que *laisser faire* puisse avoir un objet qui se réduirait en un pronom. De toute façon, ce sont **toutes** les constructions avec *laisser* et *faire* qui suivent les mêmes règles. Par contre, *falloir* **ne fait absolument pas partie** de cette catégorie (cf. *Il faut le renvoyer* vs. *Je le fais renvoyer*).

Grevisse (Bon Usage, 14e ed., §684 b) discute précisément ce cas particulier, qui s'applique selon lui aux verbes *voir, entendre, laisser, faire, écouter, regarder* et *envoyer* ainsi que leurs dérivés direct (e.g. *renvoyer*). Il y a tout un paquet d'exception (qui s'applique dans moins de cas à *laisser* et *faire*) qui demandent trois pages à être expliquées, et de toute façon, mettre le pronom entre le verbe infinitif et le conjugué est *presque toujours possible* de toute façon dans un style relevé.

Comment: _Il le faut renvoyer_ me semble d'un charme désuet.  Je le mettrais dans la bouche de mes grands-parents, pas de mes parents ni la mienne.  Hier soir, France Culture nous lisait des lettres de Diderot et je remarquai quelques autres utilisations de ce tour que je ne mettrais même pas dans la bouche de mes grands-parents.

Comment: C'est ce que je veux dire en disant que cette formule est d'un style relevé: c'est grammaticalement correct, mais certainement pas usuel dans l'usage contemporaine. C'est une formule permise, mais pas habituelle, alors qu'avec "je le fait renvoyer", l'autre construction est carrément non-grammaticale.