# Position des pronoms dans « je la laisse le finir » ou « je le lui laisse finir »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, verbes, ordre-des-mots, constructions-causatives

Ceci est issu de la page 226 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar, 5<sup>e</sup> edition* de Mary Crocker.

> #### *Laisser* and Verbs of Perception plus the Infinitive
>
> After the verb *laisser* and after the verbs of perception *entendre*, *voir*, *écouter*, *regarder* and *sentir*, the infinitive is used. Unlike in English, the infinitive precedes the noun. The pronoun precedes the main verb. These verbs unction similiarly to the verb *faire* in causative construction.
>
> Je laisse Marie finir le travail. (*I let Mary finish the work.*)
>
> Je la (lui) laisse finir le travail. (*I let her finish the work.*)
>
> Je la laisse le finir *or* Je le lui laisse finir. (*I let her finish it.*)

Je comprends comment la phrase *Je la laisse finir le travail* est construite.  Mais je ne comprends pas comment *Je le lui laisse finir* découle de celle-ci. Est-ce que cette phrase signifie la même chose, et pourquoi est-elle correcte ? Dans la première, *la* désigne Marie, l'objet direct de « laisse » ; et *le* désigne « le travail », l'objet direct de « finir ». D'où vient le « lui » ? Il n'y a pas d'objet indirect ?

De plus, si *Je le lui laisse finir* est juste, qu'en est-il de *Je lui laisse le finir* ?

Answer (score 3):

Il faut comprendre « Je le lui laisse finir » comme « Je laisse finir le travail à Marie ». *Lui* est donc un pronom (objet indirect attaché à l'auxiliaire *laisser*) qui désigne Marie. C'est le même genre de construction que [laisser faire à](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/laisser/1) (le TLF indique que cet emploi est vieilli). La signification est très proche de « Je la laisse le finir », i.e. « Je laisse Marie finir le travail », qui est un peu plus désinvolte.

Le verbe *laisser* en tant que semi-auxiliaire constitue une exception déjà décrite ici : *[Place du pronom en présence d'un verbe conjugué et l'infinitif](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8216/)* : historiquement le pronom objet de la proposition infinitive qui suit est attaché à *laisser* (uniquement lorsque qu'il est auxiliaire et par conséquent ne possède pas déjà lui-même un objet). C'est pourquoi on écrit : « Je le lui laisse finir ». Déplacer le pronom après l'auxiliaire *laisser*, i.e. « Je lui laisse le finir », n'est pas parfait (les puristes fronceront les sourcils, même si dans le langage courant cela serait bien compris) — on a tendance à l'éviter.

Comment: @Sifu: J'avais rajouté « la tache de » pour rendre la phrase grammaticalement correcte, en fait ce n'était pas la bonne façon. La formulation complète fait suivre immédatement l'auxiliaire du verbe. C'est corrigé. Merci.

Answer (score -1):

La phrase *Je le lui laisse finir* dérive d'une construction intermédiaire *je le laisse finir par elle* (cf. *Je l'envoie à elle* → *Je la lui envoie*) que Crocker omet de mentionner.

La phrase *Je lui laisse le finir* n'est pas possible parce que :

1. Elle viole, sans être une exception à (comme *Je la laisse le finir* l'est), la règle générale qui interdit de placer un pronom entre *laisser* et son infinitif objet; et
2. Elle implique que *lui* est un objet indirect de *laisser* ce qui n'est clairement pas possible dans cette construction.

Comment: Depuis quand *lui* peut remplacer un complément d'agent??